# У меня есть несколько списков, мне надо перебрать их отдельные элементы и вывести все этой отдельными строчками

Tags: python, python-3.x

Той есть у меня есть несколько списков:

```
а = [1, "синяя"]
а = [2, "белая"]
а = [3, "красная"]
а = [4, "черная"]
а = [5, "черная"]
```

И мне надо эти списки перебрать так, чтобы выдало только то что больше 2 и черное.
Выглядеть должно примерно так:

```
1: 4, черная
2: 5, черная
```

Я пытался это как то сделать с оператором for, но ничего дельного не вышло, в примерах по интернету похожего ничего не нашел.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что тут сложного то? Буквально пишете как есть:

```py
lst = [
    [1, "синяя"],
    [2, "белая"],
    [3, "красная"],
    [4, "черная"],
    [5, "черная"]
]
for n, color in lst:
    if n > 2 and color=='черная':
        print(n, color)
```